# What does Riemann mean by taking in positive sense

Tags: number-theory

In his 1859 paper Riemann analytically continued the zeta function,but he has taken integral from positive infinity to positive infinity. what does it mean? My professor says that integral from infinity to infinity is 0

Comment: Please answer in simpler terms as I am new to complex analysis

Comment: Please provide a reference to where you found this integration.

Comment: There is an equation for the zeta function in terms of a contour integral whose contour might be said to "start" at $+\infty + i0$ and "end" at $+\infty + i0$. But in 1859 the modern notation for a contour integral may not have existed (for all I know). I think the only way to know what the integral means is to look at it in the context of the paper where Riemann says what it means.

Comment: We need to know the path, not just the starting and ending points.  Also, please provide the integrand.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable question about a historically important (and confusingly phrased) integral. The short answer is that the intended contour is a contour *around the positive real axis*. Let's investigate this a bit further.

Riemann considered the integral
$$\int_C \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z - 1} dz.$$
The contour $C$ is a contour that starts at $\infty$ (and which should be regarded as occurring just below the real axis), half-encircles the origin, and then goes to $\infty$ (now regarded as occurring just above the real axis). Images of similar contours can be found by looking up images of a "keyhole contour", except that Riemann does not integrate around the outer circle.

The contour is really defined as a limit of three contours:

1. $\gamma_1(\epsilon) = \{ x - i\epsilon : 0 \leq x < \infty \}$,
2. $\gamma_2(\epsilon)$, the left-half circle centered at the origin of radius $\epsilon$, and
3. $\gamma_3(\epsilon) = \{ x + i\epsilon : 0 \leq x < \infty \}$

The intended integral is the limit of the integrals over these contours as $\epsilon \to 0$.

The reason to avoid the real line is $(-z)^{s-1}$. How does one define $(-z)^{s-1}$? We choose a branch of the logarithm and use
$$ (-z)^{s-1} := e^{(s-1)\log(-z)}.$$
The principal branch of the logarithm $\log w$ is defined for all $w$ except for $w$ on the negative real axis. Riemann uses the principal branch of the logarithm, and thus $\log(-z)$ is defined everywhere except when $z$ is on the positive real axis. Thus the contour needs to avoid the positive real axis.